# How to use a Double Dispatch with compareTo in JAVA?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern, compareto, double-dispatch

A beginner of Java... I'm a bit confused by how to apply double dispatch (and visitor pattern) together with the compareTo method in JAVA.

Example Scenario:
Let's say I have an `Animal` interface where I will implement 4 classes: *dog, cat, mouse, and bunny*.
I want to make sure that if I sort a list of these animals, mouse < bunny < cat < dog.
Wondering how I shall achieve it?
Right now the best I can think of is adding some if-elseif into the compareTo... but this is obviously not dispatchy...
Thanks!

The `Animal` interface

```
package animals;

public interface Animal extends Comparable<Animal> {
  void makeSound();
}
```

The `Dog` class

```
package animals;

public class Dog implements Animal {
  @Override public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("wow");
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(Animal o) {
    return 0; // ???? if (o instanceof Cat) {return 1}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Answer by Barskov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175475/642706) is correct and wise. Probably the best solution for your scenario is to simply add a final static `relativeSize` field to each of the four classes.

For fun, let’s look at an alternative approach using an upcoming Java feature.

## Sealed classes

The new [sealed classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397) feature being [previewed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) in [Java 16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16) makes this simpler.

When all your allowed concrete types are known at compile-time, you can communicate that fact to the compiler. Mark the class or interface as `sealed`. Add `permits` with the names of implementing/extending classes. The compiler then enforces your claim, verifying that *all* the designated classes, and *only* the designated classes, extend/implement the sealed class/interface.

We also use [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Modern Java allows an interface to have code, as a `default` method to be run if the implementing classes lack that method.

Here is some example code.

Notice the keywords: `sealed`, `permits`, and `default`.

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom;

import java.util.List;

public sealed interface Animal                    //  sealed
        extends Comparable < Animal >
        permits Mouse, Bunny, Cat, Dog            //  permits
{
    void makeSound ( );

    @Override
    default public int compareTo ( Animal o )     //  default
    {
        List < Class > animalClasses = List.of( Mouse.class , Bunny.class , Cat.class , Dog.class );
        return
                Integer.compare
                        (
                                animalClasses.indexOf( this.getClass() ) ,
                                animalClasses.indexOf( o.getClass() )
                        )
                ;
    }
}
```

The concrete classes look like the following. We use `record` here, where the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. You could just as well use a conventional class.

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom;

final public record Mouse(String name) implements Animal
{
    @Override
    public void makeSound ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Squeak." );
    }
}
```

See that in action.

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < Animal > animals =
                new ArrayList <>(
                        List.of(
                                new Mouse( "Alice" ) ,
                                new Bunny( "Bob" ) ,
                                new Cat( "Carol" ) ,
                                new Dog( "David" ) ,
                                new Mouse( "Erin" ) ,
                                new Bunny( "Frank" ) ,
                                new Cat( "Grace" ) ,
                                new Dog( "Heidi" )
                        )
                );
        System.out.println( "animals = " + animals );

        Collections.sort( animals );
        System.out.println( "animals = " + animals );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
animals = [Mouse[name=Alice], Bunny[name=Bob], Cat[name=Carol], Dog[name=David], Mouse[name=Erin], Bunny[name=Frank], Cat[name=Grace], Dog[name=Heidi]]
animals = [Mouse[name=Alice], Mouse[name=Erin], Bunny[name=Bob], Bunny[name=Frank], Cat[name=Carol], Cat[name=Grace], Dog[name=David], Dog[name=Heidi]]
```

### Do not use mere class comparison as built-in `compareTo`

The above code works, and was fun to try. But in real work you should not do this, not build-in such a `compareTo` implementation that merely looks at class only.

Read the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) Javadoc. You will see a discussion of how the `compareTo` method should be *consistent with `equals`*.

You would not consider two `Bunny` instances to be equal merely because they are both of the same class. You would also compare their content, the state of their contained data. In the case of a `record`, the default implementation of `equals` (and `hashCode`) examines each and every member field. In a conventional class, you would implement something similar, examining an `id` field or a `name` field or some such.

When you do want to compare solely by class, use an external [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) rather than implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) internally. Something like this:

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < Animal > animals =
                new ArrayList <>(
                        List.of(
                                new Mouse( "Alice" ) ,
                                new Bunny( "Bob" ) ,
                                new Cat( "Carol" ) ,
                                new Dog( "David" ) ,
                                new Mouse( "Erin" ) ,
                                new Bunny( "Frank" ) ,
                                new Cat( "Grace" ) ,
                                new Dog( "Heidi" )
                        )
                );
        System.out.println( "animals = " + animals );

        Collections.sort(
                animals ,
                new Comparator < Animal >()
                {
                    @Override
                    public int compare ( Animal o1 , Animal o2 )
                    {
                        List < Class > animalClasses = List.of( Mouse.class , Bunny.class , Cat.class , Dog.class );
                        return
                                Integer.compare
                                        (
                                                animalClasses.indexOf( o1.getClass() ) ,
                                                animalClasses.indexOf( o2.getClass() )
                                        )
                                ;
                    }
                } );
        System.out.println( "animals = " + animals );
    }
}
```

Or use the shorter lambda syntax.

```java
        Collections.sort(
                animals ,
                ( o1 , o2 ) -> {
                    List < Class > animalClasses = List.of( Mouse.class , Bunny.class , Cat.class , Dog.class );
                    return
                            Integer.compare
                                    (
                                            animalClasses.indexOf( o1.getClass() ) ,
                                            animalClasses.indexOf( o2.getClass() )
                                    )
                            ;
                } );
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid visitor pattern is not applicable here, since it requires 2 interfaces (parent types/classes): Visitor and Element. But you have only one parent type.

In your case you can just create an integer number property `size` and use it for comparison.